# homebrew installing opencv3 --with-contrib fails with use of undeclared identifier `clGetGLContextInfoKHR`

Tags: opencv, homebrew

I am trying to install opencv3 like this:

`brew install opencv3 --with-qt5 --with-opengl --with-cuda --with-ffmpeg --with-contrib`

I am getting this error:

```
/tmp/opencv320151222-25898-1l53234/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp:1646:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'clGetGLContextInfoKHR'; did you mean 'clGetContextInfo'?
        if (!clGetGLContextInfoKHR)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             clGetContextInfo
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Headers/cl.h:633:1: note: 'clGetContextInfo' declared here
clGetContextInfo(cl_context         /* context */, 
^
/tmp/opencv320151222-25898-1l53234/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp:1669:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CL_CURRENT_DEVICE_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR'
        status = clGetGLContextInfoKHR(properties, CL_CURRENT_DEVICE_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, sizeof(cl_device_id), (void*)&device, NULL);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off `With_OpenCL`.

The problem arises because your `OpenCL/cl-gl.h` doesn't contain a declaration for `clGetGLContextInfoKHR`, which is actually a part of an optional extension, and may not be installed with your version of OpenCL.